# Poner/obtener nombre de un ITEM en listView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

He creado un listView que por defecto muestra 6 elementos con un campo `Nombre` y otro `Def` de esta manera:

```
        listView.Items.Add(new grafica(){Nombre = "Seno de x", Def = "a * sen(b*x)" });
        listView.Items.Add(new grafica(){Nombre = "Coseo de x", Def = "a * cos(b*x)" });
        listView.Items.Add(new grafica(){Nombre = "Potencia de x", Def = "a*xn" });
        listView.Items.Add(new grafica(){Nombre = "Multiplo de x", Def = "a*x +b" });
        listView.Items.Add(new grafica(){Nombre = "Polinomio de x", Def = "a*x2+ b*x +c"});
        listView.Items.Add(new grafica(){Nombre = "Inversa de x", Def = "a/(b*x)" });
```

`grafica()` es solo una clase con sus set y get.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo saber en el `listView` que uno de esos elementos esta seleccionado? Hay alguna manera de nombrar un `item` y utilizar la propiedad `nombre.isChecked` para realizar operaciones con ese `item`?

Gracias!

Comment: El listview tiene propiedades que te devuelven elementos seleccionados y chequeados, como SelectedItems o CheckedItems.. que problema tenes con ellos?

Comment: Tienes que usar el binding que ofrece xaml. Para poder enlazar las propiedades de tu objeto con propiedades del control.

Comment: Pero SelectedItems es para trabajar con indices, no? @gbianchi

Comment: no. a que te referis con indices?

Comment: A trabajar de la forma SelectedItems[i]. No puedo igualarlo a un string para saber si pone seno o coseno. Eso es lo que quiero, algo como: if(listView.SelectedItems == " seno")...

Answer (score 0):

si lo que deseas es determinar cuál elemento de la lista está seleccionado puedes utilizar

```
listView.selectedItem
```

o bien

```
listView.Items[listView.SelectedIndex]
```

ahora bien, si lo que deseas es determinar el valor que se encuentra seleccionado recuerda que "grafica" es una clase que de seguro declaraste de la siguiente forma:

```
public class grafica
{
   public string Nombre {get; set; } 
   public string Def {get; set ;} 
}
```

Por tanto al ser asignada como valor del ListView debes de realizarle la conversión para su uso, es decir, por ejemplo:

```
(grafica)listView.selectedItem
```

Esto te permitirá acceder a las propiedades de tu clase y verificar su contenido de la siguiente manera:

```
if (((grafica)listView.selectedItem).Nombre.StartsWith("Seno")) 
{ 
   // Si empieza con "Seno" entonces es seno... 
}
```

Ahora bien si solo deseas determinar si se ha seleccionado un elemento del ListView o ninguno puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (listView.SelectedIndex == -1) 
{
   //No hay ningún elemento seleccionado
}
else
{
   //Hay un elemento seleccionado y ese elemento es el que 
   //se encuentra en el índice =  listView.SelectedIndex
}
```

**Esto también aplica para los ListBox**